# Prevent Docker Desktop on Windows 10 from restarting containers on startup?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

Every time I restart my computer, then try to `docker-compose up` in WSL, it fails because ports are in use. However, `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` doesn't show any conflicting ports in use.

I noticed that in Docker Desktop, my containers are running. However, `docker ps` shows no containers running. I could still `curl` my containers, so they're definitely running.

It seems like after restarting my computer, Docker Desktop automatically restarts containers in Windows (as opposed to WSL), so `docker ps` in WSL can't find the containers. How can I prevent Docker Desktop from doing this?